# how can i upload random file using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, file-upload

I instead of selecting a specific file like the example I wanted to upload a random file or select the first file from the file explorer. how can I do this?

```
your_file = "/home/you/file.doc"
file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')
file_input.send_keys(your_file)
```

Comment: Get a list of all files using `os.listdir` and upload any file from there.

Comment: how should i change in the example code? it is not working @thethiny

Comment: but I wanted the test to randomly select one of the files @thethiny

Comment: `your_file = random.choice(os.listdir('.'))`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your files are in the folder "/home/you/" if so you can do the following:

```
import os, random
file = random.choice(os.listdir("/home/you/")
file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')
file_input.send_keys(file)
```